# How do I write queries with a null constraint in pg-promise properly?

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

When writing Postgres queries, constraints are usually written like 
`WHERE a = $(a)` or `WHERE b IN $(b:csv)` if you know it's a list. However, if a value is `null`, the constraint would have to be written `WHERE x IS NULL`. Is it possible to get the query to auto-format if the value is null or not?

Say I might want to find rows `WHERE c = 1`. If I know `c` is `1`, I write the query like

```
db.oneOrNone(`SELECT * FROM blah WHERE c = $(c), { c })
```

But if `c` turns out to be `null`, the query would have to become `...WHERE c IS NULL`.

Would it be possible to construct a general query like `WHERE $(c)`, and it would automatically format to `WHERE c = 1` if `c` is `1`, and `WHERE c IS NULL` if `c` is set to null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting) to help with dynamic queries:

```js
const valueOrNull = (col, value) => ({
    rawType: true,
    toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format(`$1:name ${value === null ? 'IS NULL' : '= $2'}`,
                                    [col, value])
});
```

Then you can pass it in as a formatting value:

```js
db.oneOrNone('SELECT * FROM blah WHERE $[cnd]', { cnd: valueOrNull('col', 123) })
```

**UPDATE**

Or you can use custom formatting just for the value itself:

```js
const eqOrNull = value => ({
    rawType: true,
    toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format(`${value === null ? 'IS NULL' : '= $1'}`, value)
});
```

usage examples:

```js
db.oneOrNone('SELECT * FROM blah WHERE $1:name $2', ['col', eqOrNull(123)])
//=> SELECT * FROM blah WHERE "col" = 123

db.oneOrNone('SELECT * FROM blah WHERE $1:name $2', ['col', eqOrNull(null)])
//=> SELECT * FROM blah WHERE "col" IS NULL
```

Note that for simplicity I didn't include check for `undefined`, but you most likely will do so, because `undefined` is internally formatted as `null` also.

Comment: Thank you! I had the feeling this was it but wanted to make sure.

Comment: @BrDaHa I have updated the answer with extra examples ;)

Answer (score 0):

A very useful alternative to modifying the query depending on whether the value is `NULL` is to use [`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html).  From the reference:

> For non-null inputs, `IS DISTINCT FROM` is the same as the `<>` operator. However, if both inputs are null it returns false, and if only one input is null it returns true. Similarly, `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is identical to `=` for non-null inputs, but it returns true when both inputs are null, and false when only one input is null. Thus, these predicates effectively act as though null were a normal data value, rather than “unknown”.

In short, instead of `=`, use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`, and instead of `<>`, use `IS DISTINCT FROM`.

This becomes especially useful when comparing two columns, either of which may be null.

Note that `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` cannot use indexes, so certain queries may perform poorly.

Comment: There may be performance considerations: https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/28

Comment: That's good to know (and disappointing).  Thanks for the link.